# IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed (extending default User model)

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting this error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__auctions_user.watchlist_id

I registered 1 user before extending with the Person class, could that be why?

'''

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField('Listing')
```

'''

Comment: Your listing Model, where is it? Show your view.py also

Comment: I fixed it, I had a watchlist field on the User model from when I was extending the user model incorrectly from before. I just had to delete the previous migrations. Sorry I am totally new to Django and programming in general.